# How to obtain same left and right margin on a card with list items

Tags: vuetify.js

I'm building  a card with some items and i need to align to the right the items with texts 3576000 (plus KG icon), 120/180, and 67%. Seems that i'm doing somethig wrong, the left margin is narrow than right margin of card,

```
<div id="app">
<v-app id="inspire" fluid>
    <v-card>
        <v-list>
            <v-list-item>
                <v-list-item-content>
        <v-list-item-title class="headline">UNLOADED TRUCKS</v-list-item-title>
                </v-list-item-content>
      <v-btn icon>
        <v-icon color="primary">mdi-refresh</v-icon>
      </v-btn>
            </v-list-item>
            <v-list-item>
      <v-list-item-content>
        <v-list-item-icon>
          <v-icon color="black" size=80>mdi-truck-check</v-icon>
        </v-list-item-icon>
      </v-list-item-content>
      <v-list-item-content>
        <v-list-item class="py-n5 my-n5">
          <v-list-item-title align="right" class="px-n3 mx-n3">3576000</v-list-item-title>
          <v-list-item-icon>
            <v-icon color="black">mdi-weight-kilogram</v-icon>
          </v-list-item-icon>
        </v-list-item>
        <v-list-item>
          <v-list-item-title align="right" class="display-2">120/180</v-list-item-title>
        </v-list-item>
        <v-list-item class="py-n5 my-n5">
          <v-list-item-subtitle align="right">67%</v-list-item-subtitle>
        </v-list-item>
      </v-list-item-content>
    </v-list-item>
    <v-progress-linear value=67></v-progress-linear>
            <v-list-item class="py-n2 my-n2">
      <v-list-item-icon class="px-0 mr-1">
        <v-icon>mdi-clock</v-icon>
      </v-list-item-icon>           
      <v-list-item-subtitle>Updated 19 minutes ago</v-list-item-subtitle>
            </v-list-item>
    <v-divider></v-divider>
            <v-card-actions>
      <v-btn text color="primary">Full Report</v-btn>
    </v-card-actions>
        </v-list>
    </v-card>
</v-app>
```

sample is in https://codepen.io/wolverine4277/pen/ZEGBBze, and image show the differents margins is attached. I can't figure out how correct that, i try  between  and nothing change...

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l3ZmT.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The left and right margins of the card are okay. The issue is with the padding and margins of the list items.
If you wrap the "v-list-item-icon" with v-list-item giving it the same class (py-n5 my-n5" then it would appear fine

```
<v-list-item class="py-n5 my-n5">
    <v-list-item-icon>
        <v-icon color="black" size=80>mdi-truck-check</v-icon>
    </v-list-item-icon>
</v-list-item>
```

Comment: Perfect! i was looking in the wrong side, the missing wrapping was the key